# What can be possible reason for explosion and fire in battery pack built with 3S Li-Ios BMS

Tags: circuit-design, lithium-ion, batteries, bms, powerbanks

I recently made some 12v battery back using regular 3S Li-Ion BMS and 18650 cells.

Unfortunately, 3 of them EXPLODED and one even caught fire on site.

[image]

The BMS I used was almost exactly like [this](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B0752H8Q2R) but I bought it from Aliexpress (with high ratings) so there is no part number available. The BMS however had Overcharge, over-discharge, over-current, short circuit protection (at least as per the specifications).

I connected three cells in series and three in parallel to increase the capacity as per the use case.

[image]

I am not sure what may have gone wrong, any ideas? and what i should consider to avoid such situation again.

**Observations & questions:**

- After the incident, I started testing each and every cell separately using Opus BT/C3100 4 and it turned out that the cells were likely fake and of bad quality, because some of the cells only showed a capacity of 50-70 maH and internal resistance upto 900 ohms.
- Even if the BMS has overcharge protection, can the cells explode due to overcharge for being fake and low quality?
- Could a BMS with a balancing function avoid such an incident?

Comment: are you sure the BMS actually had overcharge protection? This is why reputable companies don't get their parts from AliExpress

Comment: Here's my recommendation. Don't buy batteries and battery management systems from shamazon or peebay or Mali-express or bang-bad unless the supplier is recognized in the industry, has a proven quality record and a data sheet is provided AND you know what you are doing.

Comment: That sounds terrible. Hope you did not get hurt. I have been warning to many, not to play with dangerous things without a knowledgeable adult supervision, whenever battery thing goes. Look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595797/powerbanks-module-getting-hot#comment1564162_595797), and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593437/is-an-ideal-diode-necessary-for-bms/594765#comment1563085_594765).

Comment: @Andyaka, is there a way to archive his posting and [picture](https://i.imgur.com/m2oD9BW.jpeg) as an example to many?

Comment: ROFL Questionable batteries + questionable BMS = Boom + Fire!!  What oh what could be the problem?  Your assumption that the device does what is advertized without testing is the biggest problem.

Comment: Would you describe the situation further - like how did you charge the batteries, with what kind of charger, power supply, etc device, and with what settings?

Comment: Here is a video of what is inside a cheap fake 18650 Lithium battery cell. It is mostly full of rice flour but it actually has a tiny real battery inside:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOshOXcSkDA

Comment: I suggest in the future you buy your BMS from a reputable source--Digikey, Mouser, Newark, or the like. Same for the batteries.

Comment: @Audioguru That battery must have FDA approval.